# Display issue with redirect on nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx

today i installed a service called staytus on my server.
It is a ruby application and run on the port :8787

But i wan't it to run on port :80.
I have redirected the port via nginx with proxy_pass.
It worked but there is only the pure text shown.
Like without using the assets.

Can anyone help me with this?

Nginx site-available default config:

```html
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80 default;
    listen [::]:80 default;
    server_name localhost;
    root /staytus/public;
    client_max_body_size 50M;
    location /assets {
      add_header Cache-Control max-age=3600;
    }
    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @puma;
    }
    location @puma {
      proxy_intercept_errors on;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8787;
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: wat do you mean by pure text.. ? Is the html being displayed on the page ? or the ruby code itself ?

Comment: the html only, without any style.
on port 8787 it works perfect.

Comment: try removing `location /assets` block in the server block for port 80.

Comment: @EJ2015 Thank you! It worked.

Comment: does this config work when you put the 8787 port and successfully redirect you to 80?

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
    root /staytus/public;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

    location @app {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}
upstream app {
    # Path to Puma
    server http://localhost:8087 fail_timeout=0;
}
```

[source](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-puma-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04)